# how to enable jquery tab after all tabs were loaded

Tags: jquery-ui-tabs

I have loaded all jquery tabs content using

$("#featured").tabs( 'load' , modul) inside a loop so that it loads 'n' number  of tabs

but all tab containers were disabled . how select at least one tab.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$("#featured").tabs('select', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this working example: http://jsfiddle.net/n4mqC/